# Django: Return id of maximum value where grouped by foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

**Information**

I have two models:

```py
class BookingModel(models.Model):

    [..fields..]


class BookingComponentModel(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = ['In Progress','Completed','Not Started','Incomplete','Filled','Partially Filled','Cancelled']
    STATUS_CHOICES = [(choice,choice) for choice in STATUS_CHOICES]
    COMPONENT_CHOICES = ['Test','Soak']
    COMPONENT_CHOICES = [(choice,choice) for choice in COMPONENT_CHOICES]

    booking = models.ForeignKey(BookingModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    component_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=COMPONENT_CHOICES)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Not Started')
    order = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    [..fields..]
```

**What I want**

I want to get the booking component for each booking which has the last value *(maximum)* in order. It will also need to have a `status='In Progress'` and `component_type='Soak'`.

For example for table:

```
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| id | booking_id | component_type | status      | order |
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| 1  | 1          | Test           | Completed   | 1     |
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| 2  | 1          | Soak           | Completed   | 2     |
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| 3  | 1          | Soak           | In Progress | 3     |
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| 4  | 2          | Test           | Completed   | 1     |
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| 5  | 2          | Soak           | In Progress | 2     |
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| 6  | 3          | Test           | In Progress | 1     |
+----+------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
```

Expected outcome would be id's: **4 & 6**

**What I've tried**

I've tried the following:

```
BookingComponentModel.objects.values('booking').annotate(max_order=Max('order')).order_by('-booking')
```

This doesn't include the filtering but returns the max_order for each booking.

I would need the id of the component which has that `max_order` in order to put this in a sub-query and enable me to filter other conditions *(status, component_type)*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a [`Subquery` expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) and work with:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

BookingModel.objects.annotate(
    latest_component_id=Subquery(BookingComponentModel.objects.filter(
        booking_id=OuterRef('pk'), status='In Progress', component_type='Soak'
    ).values('pk').order_by('-order')[:1])
)
```

The `BookingModel` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `latest_component_id` that will contain the primary key of the latest `BookingComponentModel` with as `status` `'In Progress'`, and as `component_type` `'Soak'`.

Comment: Another note to anyone who will find this answer useful. If you add `.filter(latest_component_id__isnull=False)` to the end of this query it will remove all instances that did not meet the condition.